# Is there a way in eBay / PayPal to get a list of all email addresses of people you have previously sold to?

Tags: paypal, ebay

Is there a way in eBay / PayPal to get a list of all email addresses of people you have previously sold to?

Answer (score 2):

You have three possibility:

- You can access your history transaction by the listing of customers
  [paypal listing customers](https://www.paypal.com/listing/customers)
- by a rapport of your transactions
  [export to csv](https://business.paypal.com/merchantdata/reportHome?reportType=customer-insights) 
  https://developer.paypal.com/docs/admin/download-history/
- by downloading activities
  [download history](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/admin/download-history/)